# jQuery getting element index despite wrapper / parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have divs with same class, but each 3 are wrapped in a parent div. I can't get the index the way I want it. I am sorry, could anyone help me to get the index as number from 0 to 8.. when i click on any element? despite the parent element.

Here is my full code for your testing.

```
<div class="more-content">
    <div class="post">post 1</div>
    <div class="post">post 2</div>
    <div class="post">post 3</div>
</div>
<div class="more-content">
    <div class="post">post 4</div>
    <div class="post">post 5</div>
    <div class="post">post 6</div>
</div>
<div class="more-content">
    <div class="post">post 7</div>
    <div class="post">post 8</div>
    <div class="post">post 9</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    // navigate posts with next/prev buttons
    $(".post").click(function(){
        alert($(this).index());
    });

});
</script>
```

If i click i get index 0, 1, 2 ..i think because each 3 items are wrapped in parent? I am new with jquery, any help appreciated. what i need is get the index of post with same class.. say post 6 = index 5.. and so on

**UPDATE
How can I get the same result if the clicked element is a child anchor in the post div and not the post div directly?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `index` method with `this` as an argument:

```
$(".post").click(function() {
    alert($(".post").index(this));
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nryf3/

Comment: maybe add `+ 1` to reflect the post number instead of the index in the div

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Then it won't be an index.

Comment: My mistake I thought that was what the OP was looking for

Comment: What is the alternative if I am using a link and not the actual .post how can I get alternative of index(this) if the click is anchor that is a child of .post.. and not .post itself.. ?

Comment: I mean. This solution works if the click is on .post itself, what if the click is on anchor which is a child element in .post how to make index(this) works?..

Answer (score 1):

```
var posts = $('.post').click(function(){
    alert(posts.index(this));
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/paZ2e/

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all elements tagged post and increment a counter until you find the object you're looking for, like this:

```
$(".post").click(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var that = this;

    $(".post").each(function() {
        if(that == this) break;
        counter++;
    }

    // counter now equals the index of the post element out of all posts on the page
});
```